# How do I use the Groups.pm in Request Tracker?

Tags: perl, ticket-system, rt

In lib\RT\CustomFieldValues\ there is the groups.pm file which is supposed to be an example of how to get data into a custom field, but how do I actually use that once I have written it? Does anyone have any documentation or a sample of this?

Comment: I've done many custom fields in RT 3.6.3 -- what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured it out, to use the Groups.pm module you need to go to  /opt/rt3/etc and edit the RT_SiteConfig.pm and add the line

```
Set(@CustomFieldValuesSources, "RT::CustomFieldValues::Groups");
```

Restart Apache and it will be available as a new field source.

I have written a blog post on doing this which also includes details on how to build your own module in case anyone is interested in doing this: [AD Lookup Control in Request Tracker](http://www.sadev.co.za/node/320)